# Parse Migration Tool doesn't migrate files (PFFiles)... what can I do?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I store images on Parse's managed database as a field called `imageFile`. When I ran through the [migration guide](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating) to move data out to MongoLab, I noticed that the `imageFile` field doesn't contain any binary data. Instead, it contains a file name only, like

`"imageFile": "tfss-2f493d64-2801-42ac-9861-13398549f86a-file`

How can I get all the files stored on Parse out and transferred to another location?

Comment: I just found a very relevant GitHub issue — apparently the Parse team are working on a tool that will help developers migrate files. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/8

Comment: We have also made a tool open source for migrating hosted Parse Files to Amazon S3 that worked a bit better for us: https://github.com/modernistik/parse-file-migration